# Angular Kendo Grid: Go To Page Input and Next Buttons

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, angular8

Is there a way in Kendo Grid to place a "Go to Page" Input Search button as one below? We want Both next/back buttons And a Go To Page Input. Is that possible? Trying to read through documentation.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/paging/

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on the link you provided. Go down to section Pager Types. It says :
"type—Accepts the numeric (buttons with numbers) and input (input for typing the page number) values."

Just set type to input to have a "Go to Page" input.

```
[pageable]="{
  buttonCount: buttonCount,
  info: info,
  type:'input',
  pageSizes: pageSizes,
  previousNext: previousNext
}"
```

Comment: I want it to have both, next/back, and go to page, so hopefully this will do it, I will try it out,

Comment: well, you really should read the documentation. It's all written in it. For the Previous/Next buttons, it is simply the property previousNext you set to true or false. It's independant from the go to page input.